# serve different wsgiapplications depending on request domain on GAE with threadsafe:true

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, wsgi

what im trying to do is to load different applications (webapp2.WSGIApplication) depending on the request domain.
for example www.domain_1.com should load the application in app1.main.application while www.domain_2.com should load app2.main.appplication.
of course im on the same GAE appid and im using namespaces to separate the apps data.

this works pretty good with 'threadsafe:false' and a runner.py file where a function determines which application to return

it seems that with 'threadsafe:true' the first request loads the wsgiapplication into the instance and further requests dont execute the 'application dispatching' logic any more so the request gets a response from the wrong app.

im using python2.7 and webapp2

what is the best way to do this?

**edit:**

a very simplified version of my runner.py

```
def main():
    if domain == 'www.mydomain_1.com':
        from app_1 import application
        namespace = 'app_1'
    elif domain == 'www.domain_2.com':
        from app_2 import application
        namespace = 'app_2'
    namespace_manager.set_namespace(namespace)
    return wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and in app.yaml

```
- url: /.*
  script: app-runner.py
```

Comment: Is your application code and logic different for 2 domains or is it only datastore at which you are trying to achieve seperation using namespace?

Comment: the logic is different otherwise it would have been done easily by setting a different namespace.

Comment: So you have a WSGI application within runner.py that is dispatching the request to one of several WSGI applications?  Is the "inner" application being stored in a global that overrides the dispatching logic?

Comment: @DanSanderson i edited the question and added a runner.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made it happen by subclassing webapp2.WSGIApplication and overriding `__call__()` which is called before dispatching to a RequestHandler.
prefixing routes (and removing the prefix in the handlers initialize) and substructuring config to be able to use the instance memory.

```
class CustomWSGIApplication(webapp2.WSGIApplication):

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):

        routes, settings, ns = get_app(environ)
        namespace_manager.set_namespace(ns)

        environ['PATH_INFO'] = '/%s%s' %(ns, environ.get('PATH_INFO'))

        for route in routes:
            r, h     = route # returns a tuple with mapping and handler
            newroute = ('/%s%s'%(ns, r), h,)
            self.router.add(newroute)


        if settings:
            self.config[ns] = settings

        self.debug  = debug

        with self.request_context_class(self, environ) as (request, response):
            try:
                if request.method not in self.allowed_methods:
                    # 501 Not Implemented.
                    raise exc.HTTPNotImplemented()

                rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
                if rv is not None:
                    response = rv
            except Exception, e:
                try:
                    # Try to handle it with a custom error handler.
                    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
                    if rv is not None:
                        response = rv
                except HTTPException, e:
                    # Use the HTTP exception as response.
                    response = e
                except Exception, e:
                    # Error wasn't handled so we have nothing else to do.
                    response = self._internal_error(e)

            try:
                return response(environ, start_response)
            except Exception, e:
                return self._internal_error(e)(environ, start_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your runner script is a CGI script.  The full behavior of a CGI script with multithreading turned on is not documented, and the way the docs are written I'm guessing this won't be supported fully.  Instead, the docs say you must refer to the WSGI application object directly from `app.yaml`, using the module path to a global variable containing the object, when multithreading is turned on.  (CGI scripts retain their old behavior in Python 2.7 with multithreading turned off.)

The behavior you're seeing is explained by your use of imports.  Within a single instance, each import statement only has an effect the first time it is encountered.  After that, the module is assumed to be imported and the import statement has no effect on subsequent requests.  You can import both values into separate names, then call `run()` with the appropriate value.

But if you want to enable multithreading (and that's a good idea), your dispatcher should be a WSGI application itself, stored in a module global referred to by `app.yaml`.  I don't know offhand how to dispatch a request to another WSGI application from within a WSGI application, but that might be a reasonable thing to do.  Alternatively, you might consider using or building a layer above WSGI to do this dispatch.

Comment: of course with multhreading turned on i wouldn't call CGIHandler().run(application) but return the application directly. i was thinking to put the dispatching logic within webapp2.Router but i have to figure out how to do this first.

Comment: With python27 and multithreading, the value of "script" in app.yaml is expected to be the module path to a global variable containing the WSGI application object. You can't return different WSGI application objects on a per-request basis at this level. app.yaml should refer to one WSGI application responsible for all requests handled by the app instance. Once inside this app, you can do whatever WSGI can do, including possibly dispatching to other WSGI apps.